# Android - Fix screen orientation for 1 page only (phonegap)

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova, orientation

I am having an issue with fixing the screen orientation for my index.html page only. I want to allow the app to rotate except on the home page. I understand that adding the following into you activity - android:screenOrientation="portrait" stops the screen from rotating.

However, I need to set this so it is page specific. I am using phonegap and therefore, need to stop my web view pages.

I tried calling the following activity within my manifest - com.phonegap.droidgap.index.html, however this did not work.

Could someone please advice me as to how I can define the fixed orientation for 1 page only?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use this PhoneGap Plugin for Android:

https://github.com/champierre/pg-plugin-screen-orientation

And add to your index.html page onload:

```
navigator.screenOrientation.set('portrait');
```

Comment: Hi Razvan Panda I want to know the attributes of the events of navigator object ... how can i list out them .  I explored this site http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.1/_index.html but i could find .. what i want..

Comment: Works perfectly, and a very small file size, Thank you.

Comment: Hi This works perfectly to fix the orientation, however this then fixs it for all pages. I tried adding sensor onto the other pages, however not only does this break my orginally locked page, but also does not work. Any further advice? Thanks

Comment: @weebo123: Did you add navigator.screenOrientation.set('portrait'); on index and navigator.screenOrientation.set('fullSensor'); on all other pages?

Comment: I did not add full sensor as for some reason i was getting an error message within my java so commeted that out and used sensor. Does it have to be fullsensor, and if so do you have any idea why it was not being recognised in my java (is there a specific class that i need to import?). Thanks

Comment: @weebo123: From the documentation, I'd say it has to be `fullSensor`. Could you give me the error message that you received?

Comment: SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: @weebo123: does the sample provided with the code work as intended?

Comment: My mistake, I was being stupis, forgot to import the javascript on my other pages. Thanks for this plugin.

Comment: Hi I am facing same issue but i want this in iOS is there any plugin for that?

Comment: @CrazyProggrammer: what I could find is this: http://www.skinkers.com/2012/04/24/phonegap-orientation-plugin/ you should probably ask another question, it will help others looking for the same answer

Comment: I am really sorry for that but I am blocked for asking a question so try to find my solution on this way. by the way thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the screen orientation from you code using for example `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29 . In the AndroidManifest.xml you can set it only as a global option.

Comment: Can this be set in the javascript code, or does it have to be within the java file (as my app is a web view based app). I tried adding the line you mentioned however this did not seem to stop the orientation. Thanks

Comment: Needs to be in the java file.