# PhoneGap Disable Screen Rotate On Single Page?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am using PhoneGap, and am working with an Android web based app.

How do I disable screen rotation for only one page?

I have searched for this solution but all the solutions say to disable screen rotation in the AndroidManifest.xml file. However, this disables rotation for the whole app. I only need to disable rotation for one page.

Can this be done using PhoneGap / Javascript code? I am not using any Java code.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/10348538/1321873

Comment: i get the following error

The method setRequestedOrientation(int) is undefined for the type CordovaInterface

i followed the instruction guide. any suggestions? i could not find a solution to this error. I am doing all of my programming in javascript / html canvas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this post is a few months old but there is a plugin for phonegap which can help you...
It is a plugin that can lock or unlock screen orientation.

[OrientationLock - Android PhoneGap](https://github.com/cogitor/PhoneGap-OrientationLock)

Comment: Thank you. This is the best answer yet. Hopefully phonegap comes out with a cross-platform solution soon.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply remove the following tag or set it at 'portrait' in your config.xml file :

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

For more informations, read the phonegap documentation :

https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

Comment: Thx for the reply. However setting that variable will set the orientation for the whole app. As per the original question I am attempting to fix orientation for only certain pages which would have to be done via phonegap API or jQuery so it can be called in the page code.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple way to lock rotation:

1/. Edit in config.xml file:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

2/. Put this code into Android Manifestxml file in:

```
<activity>
    ...
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    ...
</activity>
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. However setting that variable will set the orientation for the whole app. As per the original question I am attempting to fix orientation for only certain pages which would have to be done via phonegap API or jQuery so it can be called in the page code