# disable landscape orientation only for certain html pages

Tags: cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - Fix screen orientation for 1 page only (phonegap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348538/android-fix-screen-orientation-for-1-page-only-phonegap)

I found ways to disable landscape orientation (both for android and iOS), but the solutions all apply for the whole app. I need to disable landscape orientation only for certain html Pages. Anyone knows how to do this or where I can get further information to it?

Comment: u can use [pg-plugin-screen-orientation](https://github.com/champierre/pg-plugin-screen-orientation) for phonegap & in ur html onload event put this line: `navigator.screenOrientation.set('portrait');` for more detail see [Android - Fix screen orientation for 1 page only (phonegap)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348538/android-fix-screen-orientation-for-1-page-only-phonegap) Similar Issue