# Restrict orientation change in a single JQM page

Tags: android, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a phonegap application built using jQuery mobile. It uses jQuery mobile multi-page template structure to display pages.

Is it possible to restrict the orientation of a single page to portrait. The other pages need to continue handling orientation changes normally.

The purpose is to display a page with an image containing data and page footer with buttons. The portrait image has to be displayed completely. This was done by setting width 100% in css. This causes issues in landscape orientation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Click to see the link, you may get solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/10349014/2423870

Comment: Thanks power_scriptor. The solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a plugin for orientation change

Pull it from [github](https://github.com/vicky-gonsalves/OrientationChanger)